# Control ASP.NET WebAPI JSON serialisation without access to source code

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET WebAPI to return an object from an assembly that I can't change the source code in.

I want to remove one property from the response, but I cannot simply add [JsonIgnore] to that property because I can't edit the class I am returning.

Is there a way to specify a separate property ignore list?

There serialization is happening automatically at the moment using the Ok() method:

```
return Ok(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver` to conditionally serialize properties.

For more info on Json.net's support in this space, you can take a look at the following link:
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ContractResolver.htm

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();

public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : System.Net.Formatting.JsonContractResolver
{
    public new static readonly ShouldSerializeContractResolver Instance = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(Employee) && property.PropertyName == "Manager")
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize =
                instance =>
                {
                    Employee e = (Employee)instance;
                    return e.Manager != e;
                };
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```